# In what context is this IP address / subnet mask valid?

Tags: ipv4, ip-address

Is this IP address ever valid? I am reviewing a CCNA course taken by thousands of previous students. The information I have isn't in the right order / context, but I noticed that this IP address was listed in a table as a configuration

10.0.10.0/24 - this was for a fast ethernet port on a switch, that is part of a VLAN titled "Sales Department".

Have I forgotten my basic networking or what?

Answer (score 2):

That 10.0.10.0/24 address is interpreted by computers to mean the *network address* is 10.0.10.0; network engineers might refer to this as the "10.0.10 network." That /24 is the *subnet mask* defining which part of that IP address refers to the *network address*.

There are two reserved addresses in all IPv4 networks, excluding those with a /32 bit mask. - the *network address* and the *broadcast address*. In your specific case 10.0.10.0 is the *network address* and 10.0.10.255 is the *broadcast address*.

Answer (score 1):

10.0.10.0/24 isn't a usable host address (by the convention that the host bits may not be all zero), but it is a valid subnet address/prefix as used inside a VLAN.

Likely, that label is intended to point out the subnet prefix used inside the VLAN, but without specific context it's hard to say.

Comment: What are the commands I need to be able to assign VLAN "Sales" the 10.0.10.0/24 subnet/prefix , assuming the VLAN has already been created? Would be super helpful thanks!!

Comment: You assign IP addresses (with a shared prefix) to interfaces connected to a VLAN, but you can't assign a prefix to the VLAN itself. A VLAN is a layer-2 construct - picture a virtual switch.